# How do I use an array that has been passed into a pug template, in a javascript function without it being split?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have a CRUD.js file which I'm using to pass some variables, including an array, into a pug template called list.pug:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  let {projects, nextPageToken} = await db.list(10, req.query.pageToken);
  let customers = ["John", "Mary", "Mark"];

  res.render('projects/list.pug', {
    projects,
    nextPageToken,
    customers,
  });
});
```

Then within the pug file, I'm trying to build a table using javascript, by looping through these arrays. When I do this however, it seems that rather than customers being seen as an array of strings, it's seen as one string (a similar issue occurs when trying to loop through projects). Here is the pug template with the javascript:

```
  select(name="customerDropdown", id="customerDropdown" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" onChange="changeEvent()")
    each customer in customers 
      option=customer

  each project in projects
      .media
        a(href=`/projects/${project.id}`)
          .media-body
            h4= "Customer: " + project.customer
            p= "Project manager: " + project.manager

  if !projects.length
    p No projects found.

  if nextPageToken
    nav
      ul.pager
        li
          a(href=`?pageToken=${encodeURIComponent(nextPageToken)}`) More
 script.
    let projects = "!{projects}"
    let customers = "!{customers}"

    console.log(customers.length)
    for (var i = 0; i < customers.length; i++){
      console.log(customers[i])
    }
```

This code results in each individual character of customers being printed out (i.e.'J', 'O', 'H', 'N', ',', 'M', etc.) rather than: "John", "Mary", "Mark", although the "each customer in customers" loop works fine in "customerDropdown". I'm trying to use this array to dynamically update the page, so how do I pull it in to the JS fucntion as the original array rather than as a string/array of characters? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass an array from Pug to client-side javascript, you'll need to drop the quote marks and use `JSON.stringify()` during interpolation, like this:

```
script.
  let projects  = !{JSON.stringify(projects)}
  let customers = !{JSON.stringify(customers)}
```